# MySQL How to check empty periods between two dates

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql table like this:

```
| ID | date_start |  date_end  |
| 1  | 2013-10-17 | 2013-10-18 |
| 2  | 2013-10-28 | 2013-10-31 |
```

I need to check empty periods between two dates.

To retrieve records from a date range I do:

```
SELECT * FROM `periods` WHERE ((date_start <= '2013-10-18' AND date_end >= '2013-10-18' AND date_end <= '2013-10-31') OR (date_start >= '2013-10-18' AND date_start <= '2013-10-31' AND date_end >= '2013-10-31') OR (date_start >= '2013-10-18' AND date_end <= '2013-10-31') OR (date_start <= '2013-10-18' AND date_end >= '2013-10-31'))
```

In php I can check it out through the while loop, but is there a mysql query that can be checked this?

```
$first = true;
$emptyPeriod = false;
while ($period = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if($first) {
        $first = false;
        $prevEndPeriod = $period['date_end'];
        continue;
    }

    $nextDay = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($prevEndPeriod . ' + 1 day'));

    if($nextDay != $period['date_start']) {
        $emptyPeriod = true;
        break;
    } else {
        $prevEndPeriod = $period['date_end'];
    }

}

echo ($emptyPeriod) ? 'Empty period' : 'OK';
```

Comment: use DATEDIFF http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff

Answer (score 0):

Use `DATEDIFF` function of Mysql:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF('2013-10-17','2013-10-18');
```

For more info check this link:
http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/163-how-to-calculate-the-interval-between-two-dates-or-times-in-mysql/

OR

Using php:

```
floor(( strtotime( $endDate ) - strtotime( $startDate ) ) / 86400);
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem or I don't understand. I need to check empty periods between two dates, example: date range 2013-10-17 to 2013-10-31 empty periods is 2013-10-19 to 2013-10-27.

Answer (score 0):

The following query will give you the start dates of overlapping periods. If there are more than one, there is a empty period in between.

```
select distinct s.date_start
from periods s
left join periods e
    on date_diff(s.date_start, e.date_end) <= 0
        and date_diff(s.date_start, e.date_end) >= -1
where e.id is null
```

Your php code would be:

```
echo (mysql_num_rows($result)>1) ? 'Empty period' : 'OK';
```

If you need the start and end dates of the empty periods, you could get the end dates of overlapping periods in a similar manner, and go a step further.